# Can I use an NTE2374 as a power switch?

Tags: mosfet

I have been playing around with an NTE2374 to try and make a simple power switch (forgive me if my terminology is off, the MOSFET is supposed to toggle on/off the power to a circuit - that's what I mean by power switch.)

I have configured the MOSFET to be in common source mode, with the gate connected to the control signal, the drain connected to the load in question, and the source connected to ground.

When I use a microcontroller to toggle the signal, the LED's brightness is faint.  When using ground/Vdd as the control signal, the LED is much brighter.

What do I need to do to make the microcontroller able to toggle the LED such that the LED is bright (not faint) when the appropriate signal is given?

Here is a simple schematic:

[image]

Comment: noice way to pop your LED and mosfet this. ESP32 has adjustable output drive strength on the GPIOs. But in principle it should not matter for steady state, as the mosfet gate is effectively a small capacitor. Figure 3.96 in art of electronics 3rd. ed has some mosfet power switch examples. I would choose a transistor with a lower vgs threshold voltage. But for that amount of specified current I'm guessing most mosfets needs a higher VGS...

Comment: Did you measure what voltage are you getting from ESP pin? Also what Vdd you mean during manual switching? 3V3?

Comment: @user55924 , didn't know esp32 has adjustable drive strength, cool! And very cool for the art of electronics reference, was looking at 3.106 instead, thanks. Will take a look.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický , I did, the output of a esp pin is around 3.25v. Sorry not sure what you mean about the Vdd question, by Vdd I mean the 9v battery that is shown in the schematic above.

Comment: You're almost exactly spot-on with your terminology -- usually we'd just say "switch" instead of "power switch".  We'd trust the reader to understand the "power" bit from the overall function of the circuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/2300to2399/pdf/nte2374.pdf), the gate threshold voltage can be anywhere from 2.0 to 4.0 V, depending on manufacturing variations, ambient temperature, etc. This threshold voltage is where the transistor *barely* turns on, so you'll need to exceed it with some margin to actually drive a load.

As a result, you can't rely on it turning on at 3.3 V. You might find that some units, at some temperatures, do work well with 3.3V gate drive, and others don't.

To use the circuit topology that was shown, you'll want to search for an N-type MOSFET that has the current handling capability you require as well as a lower threshold voltage.

Alternatively, you may use an additional circuit to drive the gate with a higher voltage (close to VDD and GND):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f64Gpc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit relies on a couple of resistors and an additional NPN transistor. A small common type like a 2N3904 or any other small NPN transistor can be used - whichever you have on hand is OK.

The NPN transistor acts in a common-emitter operation, analogous to the common-source operation of the MOSFET. When the pin is high, Q1 is on, and sinks current, pulling down M1's gate voltage to a small voltage on the order of 0.1 or 0.2 V. This is reliably low enough to turn off M1.

When the pin is low, Q1 is cut off, and the voltage at Q1's collector (i.e. M1's gate) is pulled up to VDD (i.e. 9V, well above the worst case threshold voltage, but within the maximum Vgs rating of M1) by the resistor. Hence, current flows in the load.

Note that this requires the high/low signals to be inverted in software compared to the initial setup: unlike the original circuit, HIGH turns the load off and LOW turns the load on. This is also rather slow; you won't be able to do high-frequency switching or PWM reliably with this setup - at that point you'll probably want to use a real gate driver chip anyway.

Comment: It's worth noting, in addition to your first paragraph, that just having a threshold voltage less than 3.3 V is not enough to mean that it will work at 3.3 V. The threshold voltage is the voltage at which the FET just barely begins to turn on, usually defined as the voltage at which the FET lets through something in the range of 10 to 100 μA of drain current (sometimes as much as 1 mA for very large power devices). You typically need to drive a FET with a voltage at least a volt or three above its threshold voltage. (I know you know this, nanofarad, just for the asker's benefit!)

Comment: Another point worth noting -- which may be immaterial in the context of this question -- is that the gate driver here will be _slow_, meaning it's good for pulse widths in the tenths or perhaps hundredths of seconds, but not shorter.  If you need fast turn-on and turn-off (as in, for instance, a switching power supply or 10kHz PWM to a motor) then you'd need a gate driver.

Answer (score 3):

One of the key factors in using MOSFETs as switches is to find their \$\mathrm{R_{DS(on)}}\$ rating in the data sheet.  There should be a note or a column saying at what \$V_{GS}\$ that \$\mathrm{R_{DS(on)}}\$ rating applies.  In the case of your NTE2374 that's 10V.

You should then make sure that your circuit supplies an on-state gate-source voltage between that rated \$V_{GS}\$ and the maximum rating (20V in this case).  Note that \$\pm 20 \mathrm V\$ is practically ubiquitous for modern silicon power FETs.  So you'd want to drive this one at between 12V and 18V to give yourself some margin between 10V and 20 volts.

In your case, if you wanted to use a gate drive of 3.3V, you'd want to first shop for "logic level" FETs, then read each data sheet and make sure they have the \$\mathrm{R_{DS(on)}}\$ you need at a gate voltage of 3.3V.  There's lots of "logic level" FETs that only reach their rated \$\mathrm{R_{DS(on)}}\$ with a gate voltage of 5V, which wouldn't work for you in this case.

Comment: You're just missing it--on page 1 of [this datasheet](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/2300to2399/pdf/nte2374.pdf), the absolute maximum gate-source voltage is specified as ±20 V.

Comment: Edited, and thank you for assisting me in basic reading comprehension.  I _did_ look at the front page -- really, I did!